# Construct simple 1D probability contours in r

Tags: ggplot2

I want to recreate an image like the attached for my own data in R.

[Green and Theobald. Sexing birds by discriminant analysis: further considerations. 1989. IBIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH3Gx.png)

An example of my data:

```
df <- data.frame (sex  = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "F"),
                  wing = c(110,110,115,113,113),
                  bill = c(24,24,26,25,28)
)
```

I've plotted my real data using the following code just fine, but want to add lines representing 0.01, 0.5, 0.99 probability of a bird being male given bill and wing.

```
Dunlin_abbrev %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(Bill, Wing, color = Sex))+
      geom_point()
```

The attached graph is from a Green and Theobald (1989) paper that used a discriminant function analysis to predict bird gender by bill and wing length.

The paper said they constructed a graph with contours corresponding to specified probabilities a bird is a male. However, all my searches for "probability contours" give me 2D contour lines that completely encircle my data like mapping a mountain such as geom_contour(), rather than the simple 1D splitting line I desire.

Comment: I assume (not an expert in birds gender), that in order for you to draw those probability lines, you need to know where to place them. If you have such data, please edit your question and share it. As the problem stands, I can't tell where to put the line. As to _how to draw the lines_, once we know where to place them, we could use `geom_abline` or some similar function to actually draw them.